# glGetError() after glTexParameter() always return GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: opengl

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
GLuint err = glGetError();
```

If I set `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE's GL_TEXTURE_WARP to GL_REPEAT, glGetError()` will always return

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION.

: GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE -> GL_TEXTURE_2D  return GL_NO_ERRORS

: GL_REPEAT -> GL_CLAMP return GL_NO_ERRORS
```

...How to solve this?

i need to call `glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

-- sorry about this post... Stupid.. TEXTURE_RECTANGLE not allow GL_REPEAT...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know all the details, but the short answer is: `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE` doesn't support `GL_REPEAT`. You'll have to find another solution.